How to stack colors in area chart
Just wanted to share one way you can can stack different colors or "zones" in an area chart.
In the example below I made a chart for a fitness app to track how your pulse goes through different heart rate zone during a spinning session. I use vconcat to combine the data. Give it a like if you find this useful.

{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "title": "Today's workout: heart rate.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"x": 0, "y": 85},
      {"x": 1, "y": 85},
      {"x": 2, "y": 87},
      {"x": 3, "y": 79},
      {"x": 4, "y": 85},
      {"x": 5, "y": 83},
      {"x": 6, "y": 80},
      {"x": 7, "y": 77},
      {"x": 8, "y": 83},
      {"x": 9, "y": 79},
      {"x": 10, "y": 71},
      {"x": 11, "y": 95},
      {"x": 12, "y": 77},
      {"x": 13, "y": 89},
      {"x": 14, "y": 95},
      {"x": 15, "y": 93},
      {"x": 16, "y": 90},
      {"x": 17, "y": 97},
      {"x": 18, "y": 93},
      {"x": 19, "y": 89},
      {"x": 20, "y": 99},
      {"x": 21, "y": 105},
      {"x": 22, "y": 107},
      {"x": 23, "y": 109},
      {"x": 24, "y": 105},
      {"x": 25, "y": 103},
      {"x": 26, "y": 100},
      {"x": 27, "y": 107},
      {"x": 28, "y": 103},
      {"x": 29, "y": 119},
      {"x": 30, "y": 111},
      {"x": 31, "y": 135},
      {"x": 32, "y": 137},
      {"x": 33, "y": 139},
      {"x": 34, "y": 135},
      {"x": 35, "y": 133},
      {"x": 36, "y": 130},
      {"x": 37, "y": 137},
      {"x": 38, "y": 133},
      {"x": 39, "y": 139},
      {"x": 40, "y": 151},
      {"x": 41, "y": 155},
      {"x": 42, "y": 157},
      {"x": 43, "y": 159},
      {"x": 44, "y": 155},
      {"x": 45, "y": 153},
      {"x": 46, "y": 150},
      {"x": 47, "y": 157},
      {"x": 48, "y": 153},
      {"x": 49, "y": 159},
      {"x": 50, "y": 170},
      {"x": 51, "y": 165},
      {"x": 52, "y": 177},
      {"x": 53, "y": 179},
      {"x": 54, "y": 185},
      {"x": 55, "y": 183},
      {"x": 56, "y": 188},
      {"x": 57, "y": 197},
      {"x": 58, "y": 193},
      {"x": 59, "y": 205},
      {"x": 60, "y": 191},
      {"x": 61, "y": 185},
      {"x": 62, "y": 187},
      {"x": 63, "y": 189},
      {"x": 64, "y": 185},
      {"x": 65, "y": 183},
      {"x": 66, "y": 180},
      {"x": 67, "y": 187},
      {"x": 68, "y": 183},
      {"x": 69, "y": 179},
      {"x": 70, "y": 161},
      {"x": 71, "y": 165},
      {"x": 72, "y": 157},
      {"x": 73, "y": 159},
      {"x": 74, "y": 155},
      {"x": 75, "y": 153},
      {"x": 76, "y": 150},
      {"x": 77, "y": 157},
      {"x": 78, "y": 153},
      {"x": 79, "y": 159},
      {"x": 80, "y": 160}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "0", "as": "min"},
    {"calculate": "90", "as": "L1"},
    {"calculate": "143", "as": "L2"},
    {"calculate": "166", "as": "L3"},
    {"calculate": "181", "as": "L4"},
    {"calculate": "200", "as": "L5"},
    {"calculate": "220", "as": "max"}
  ],
  "params": [
    {"name": "min", "expr": "data('data_0')[0]['min']"},
    {"name": "L0", "expr": "data('data_0')[0]['L0']"},
    {"name": "L1", "expr": "data('data_0')[0]['L1']"},
    {"name": "L2", "expr": "data('data_0')[0]['L2']"},
    {"name": "L3", "expr": "data('data_0')[0]['L3']"},
    {"name": "L4", "expr": "data('data_0')[0]['L4']"},
    {"name": "L5", "expr": "data('data_0')[0]['L5']"},
    {"name": "max", "expr": "data('data_0')[0]['max']"}
  ],
  "spacing": -1,
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "height": 80,
      "width": 200,
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "line",
            "color": "#5c5c5c",
            "clip": true,
            "interpolate": "monotone"
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "x",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "y",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[min,max]"}, "nice": false},
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "height": 80,
      "width": 600,
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "line",
            "align": "left",
            "baseline": "top",
            "font": "Arial",
            "fontSize": 13,
            "color": "black",
            "size": 1,
            "strokeDash": [2, 2]
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
            "y": {
              "field": "max",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[L5,max]"}},
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "line",
            "color": "black",
            "clip": true,
            "interpolate": "monotone"
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "x",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "y",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[L5,max]"}, "nice": false},
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "area",
            "color": "black",
            "opacity": 0.5,
            "clip": true,
            "interpolate": "monotone"
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "x",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "y",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[L5,max]"}, "nice": false},
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "transform": [
            {"filter": "datum.x == 0"},
            {
              "calculate": "'Zone 6 (*pain): ' + format(datum.L5 , '.0f') + ' ~ ' + format(datum.max , '.0f')",
              "as": "zone_desc"
            }
          ],
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "align": "left",
            "baseline": "top",
            "dy": 10,
            "dx": 5,
            "font": "Arial",
            "fontSize": 13,
            "color": "#5c5c5c"
          },
          "encoding": {
            "text": {"field": "zone_desc", "type": "nominal"},
            "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
            "y": {
              "field": "max",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "height": 80,
      "width": 600,
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "line",
            "align": "left",
            "baseline": "top",
            "font": "Arial",
            "fontSize": 13,
            "color": "red",
            "size": 1,
            "strokeDash": [2, 2]
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
            "y": {
              "field": "L5",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[L4,L5]"}},
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "line",
            "color": "red",
            "clip": true,
            "interpolate": "monotone"
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "x",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "y",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[L4,L5]"}, "nice": false},
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "area",
            "color": "red",
            "opacity": 0.5,
            "clip": true,
            "interpolate": "monotone"
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "x",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "y",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[L4,L5]"}, "nice": false},
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "transform": [
            {"filter": "datum.x == 0"},
            {
              "calculate": "'Zone 5: ' + format(datum.L4 , '.0f') + ' ~ ' + format(datum.L5 , '.0f')",
              "as": "zone_desc"
            }
          ],
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "align": "left",
            "baseline": "top",
            "dy": 10,
            "dx": 5,
            "font": "Arial",
            "fontSize": 13,
            "color": "#5c5c5c"
          },
          "encoding": {
            "text": {"field": "zone_desc", "type": "nominal"},
            "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
            "y": {
              "field": "L5",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "height": 80,
      "width": 600,
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "line",
            "align": "left",
            "baseline": "top",
            "font": "Arial",
            "fontSize": 13,
            "color": "orange",
            "size": 1,
            "strokeDash": [2, 2]
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
            "y": {
              "field": "L4",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[L3,L4]"}},
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "line",
            "color": "orange",
            "clip": true,
            "interpolate": "monotone"
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "x",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "y",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[L3,L4]"}, "nice": false},
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "area",
            "color": "orange",
            "opacity": 0.5,
            "clip": true,
            "interpolate": "monotone"
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "x",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "y",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[L3,L4]"}, "nice": false},
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "transform": [
            {"filter": "datum.x == 0"},
            {
              "calculate": "'Zone 4: ' + format(datum.L3 , '.0f') + ' ~ ' + format(datum.L4 , '.0f')",
              "as": "zone_desc"
            }
          ],
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "align": "left",
            "baseline": "top",
            "dy": 10,
            "dx": 5,
            "font": "Arial",
            "fontSize": 13,
            "color": "#5c5c5c"
          },
          "encoding": {
            "text": {"field": "zone_desc", "type": "nominal"},
            "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
            "y": {
              "field": "L4",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "height": 80,
      "width": 600,
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "line",
            "align": "left",
            "baseline": "top",
            "font": "Arial",
            "fontSize": 13,
            "color": "#afac0b",
            "size": 1,
            "clip": true,
            "strokeDash": [2, 2]
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
            "y": {
              "field": "L3",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[L2,L3]"}},
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "line",
            "color": "#afac0b",
            "clip": true,
            "interpolate": "monotone"
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "x",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "y",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[L2,L3]"}},
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "area",
            "color": "#e4e116",
            "opacity": 0.5,
            "clip": true,
            "interpolate": "monotone"
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "x",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "y",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[L2,L3]"}},
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "transform": [
            {"filter": "datum.x == 0"},
            {
              "calculate": "'Zone 3: ' + format(datum.L2 , '.0f') + ' ~ ' + format(datum.L3 , '.0f')",
              "as": "zone_desc"
            }
          ],
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "align": "left",
            "baseline": "top",
            "dy": 10,
            "dx": 5,
            "font": "Arial",
            "fontSize": 13,
            "color": "#5c5c5c"
          },
          "encoding": {
            "text": {"field": "zone_desc", "type": "nominal"},
            "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
            "y": {
              "field": "L3",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "height": 80,
      "width": 600,
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "line",
            "align": "left",
            "baseline": "top",
            "font": "Arial",
            "fontSize": 13,
            "color": "#19be0d",
            "size": 1,
            "strokeDash": [2, 2]
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
            "y": {
              "field": "L2",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[L1,L2]"}},
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "line",
            "color": "#19be0d",
            "clip": true,
            "interpolate": "monotone"
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "x",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "y",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[L1,L2]"}, "nice": false},
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "area",
            "color": "#19be0d",
            "opacity": 0.5,
            "clip": true,
            "interpolate": "monotone"
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "x",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "y",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[L1,L2]"}, "nice": false},
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "transform": [
            {"filter": "datum.x == 0"},
            {
              "calculate": "'Zone 2: ' + format(datum.L1 , '.0f') + ' ~ ' + format(datum.L2 , '.0f')",
              "as": "zone_desc"
            }
          ],
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "align": "left",
            "baseline": "top",
            "dy": 10,
            "dx": 5,
            "font": "Arial",
            "fontSize": 13,
            "color": "#5c5c5c"
          },
          "encoding": {
            "text": {"field": "zone_desc", "type": "nominal"},
            "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
            "y": {
              "field": "L2",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "height": 80,
      "width": 600,
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "line",
            "align": "left",
            "baseline": "top",
            "font": "Arial",
            "fontSize": 13,
            "color": "#0d8de2",
            "size": 1,
            "strokeDash": [2, 2]
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
            "y": {
              "field": "L1",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "line",
            "color": "#0d8de2",
            "clip": true,
            "interpolate": "monotone"
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
            "y": {
              "field": "y",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[min,L1]"}, "nice": false},
              "axis": {"title": null, "labels": false, "grid": false}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "area",
            "color": "#0d8de2",
            "opacity": 0.5,
            "clip": true,
            "interpolate": "monotone"
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "x",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {
                "title": "Minutes of workout",
                "ticks": true,
                "labels": true,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": true
              }
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "y",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[min,L1]"}, "nice": false},
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "transform": [
            {"filter": "datum.x == 0"},
            {
              "calculate": "'Zone 1: ' + format(datum.min , '.0f') + ' ~ ' + format(datum.L1 , '.0f')",
              "as": "zone_desc"
            }
          ],
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "align": "left",
            "baseline": "top",
            "dy": 40,
            "dx": 5,
            "font": "Arial",
            "fontSize": 13,
            "color": "#000000"
          },
          "encoding": {
            "text": {"field": "zone_desc", "type": "nominal"},
            "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
            "y": {
              "field": "L1",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {
                "title": null,
                "ticks": false,
                "labels": false,
                "grid": false,
                "domain": false
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "config": {"view": {"stroke": null}}
}


I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question. Use other channels for promoting your work.

Hi @IvankaTodorova, I am just sharing some code with community. This logic to have multi colored area charts is often asked about and it tricky to accomplish. I'm not trying to promote my work though. Thanks

sharing is great! Thank you! SO is QA-based platform and you've provided a solution in the part where the question should be in. I suggest you read those two links: Can I answer my own question and Etiquette for answering your own question. Alternatively, you said it's a question that people ask often, you can go and post your content as answers there.
